# installing mod_wsgi: missing architecture file

Tags: macos, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

I am installing mod_wsgi for python3.3.1 on Mac. I saw this warning and am quite stumped even after looking through the installing documentation.

```
./configure --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.3
```

`make` returns:

```
/usr/sbin/apxs -c -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m -DNDEBUG  -Wc,'-arch x86_64' -Wc,'-arch i386' -Wc,'-arch ppc7400' mod_wsgi.c -Wl,-F/Library/Frameworks -framework Python -framework CoreFoundation   -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch ppc7400 -ldl  -framework CoreFoundation
/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch ppc7400 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/include/python3.3m -DNDEBUG  -c -o mod_wsgi.lo mod_wsgi.c && touch mod_wsgi.slo
/usr/share/apr-1/build-1/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -o mod_wsgi.la  -rpath /usr/libexec/apache2 -module -avoid-version    mod_wsgi.lo -Wl,-F/Library/Frameworks -framework Python -framework CoreFoundation -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch ppc7400 -ldl -framework CoreFoundation
```

**The "warning" is as follows:**

```
ld: warning: in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Python, missing required architecture ppc in file
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch i386)
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch ppc7400)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the generated Makefile and remove the option:

```
-Wc,'-arch ppc'
```

from CFLAGS, and the option:

```
-arch ppc
```

from LDFLAGS.

It happens because your Apache installation is a fat executable with ppc support still in it, but the OS no longer supports building ppc.

The build scripts use what is compiled into Apache to work out what mod_wsgi should be compiled for.